# Different path to shared drives linked to macro button

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem that the computer service constantly keep changing the server, the mapped drive letter always stay the same.

\XXRDC1\prototech-dfs-1

\XX.XXX.no\prototech-dfs-1

which are mapped to z:\

I try to link buttons in excel to a macro on a shared drive, this works fine as long as the network server does not change. After the macro is loaded it looks like this:

[image]

before it looks like this:

[image]

It seems like it save with the active path, but does not display it, the problem is when the shared drive move server.. Is there a workaround to avoid this? The buttons can be created with a macro, which I could run on every workbook open event. But this seems like overload.

Comment: only one of the macros sit on a workbook in the shared drive? Do you have the rest of your macros on the workbook you are using? Do you have multiple users or it is only one user all the time?

Comment: All macros sit on the shared drive in one excel file(.xlam) and these macros are called simoultainously by several useres from different workbooks on the client site.

Comment: if it is an xlam file you should actually install it as an add-in on each user's machine so you would not use one instance by multiple users, this would cause accessing problems.

Comment: If the macros are trying to have access to a file somewhere in the share network (that has an ever changing alias) then you best bet it to use File System Object (FSO) or DIR function to locate the file in that directory and then get its address. Since this search may take some time, this should happen once you load the add-in or you should save it under a NAME in NAMES and you should run that function the moment that address become invalid. The new path should be captured and saved under the name again

Comment: Ok, got the concept. I will add a workbook_open event in all workbooks using the addin and checking for the path of the addin workbook and if this is changed then regenerate the buttons